# How to scrape only active div

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape a page and I want to get the divs that are not hidden... I am using nokogiri for scraping.

```
status = doc.css('.fi-mu__m').map {|status| status.css('.fi-mu__score-info').css('.fi-s__status--abbr').css('.period .full_time').map(&:text)}
```

I need something else instead of `.period` and `.full_time`

Here is copy of the part of the DOM:

```
<div class="fi-s__status--abbr">

      <span class="period cancelled hidden">

    Annulé
      </span>
      <span class="period lineups hidden">

    Comp.
      </span>
      <span class="period half_time hidden">

    MT
      </span>
      <span class="period extra_time hidden">

    Fin 2ème MT
      </span>
      <span class="period extra_half_time hidden">

    End 1H ET
      </span>
      <span class="period penalty_shootout hidden">

    TAB
      </span>
      <span class="period full_time">

    Fin
      </span>
      <span class="period post_match  hidden">

    Fin
      </span>
      <span class="period minute hidden">0'</span>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.css('.period .full_time:not(.hidden)')`

see the [:not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)